# Which potentiometer to use?

Tags: potentiometer, 12v

New to electronics...so learning as I go. I have a 12vDC 1.5amp power supply that I will be using to power a 12vDC .30a computer fan. I want to use a potentiometer to adjust the speed of the fan but I'm not sure how I go about determining which potentiometer values I need. I've looked at a few of the formulas and calculators online but they're a bit over my head right now.

Comment: What have you tried?  What formulas have you used?  Why do you think these are wrong? Or what about these do you not understand?  Please read the [About](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/about) page.  We are looking for questions which "include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Comment: Does the fan have a four-pin connector or a three-pin connector? Fans with four-pin connectors typically use PWM control of fan speed.

Comment: My fan actually has a 2 wire grove connector. I think I understand that R = 13/.3 given the above...which should give me a 40 Ohm pot at 4 (3.6 really) watts? That just seems rather high and I feel like I'm missing something or not understanding something.

Answer (score 3):

I found this which might be helpful:

http://img.techpowerup.org/100617/fancontroller.png
[image]

You might need to adjust Q3 based on your stated power supply.

EDIT:  I should add the source of that:

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=124633

That discussion also talk about using just a trimpot vs PWM.

Answer (score 0):

Computer fan speed can be controlled over a certain range using a variable voltage. However the range lower level speeds will be limited using this technique. Instead you should get a computer fan with a 3-wire connection and use the speed control wire with a 0-5 volt PWM signal. This will give you the greatest range of speed control while at the same time assuring that the fan will still spin up at startup time.